# Округлить TextField javaFX

Tags: javafx, gui, style

В приложении на JAVAFX хочу добавить картинку к TextField, но в сам TextField её добавить вроде нельзя поэтому надо округлить его лишь с 1й стороны, чтобы можно было с другой картинку добавить. Не знаю как это сделать пытался с помощью CSS
-fx-background-radius: 0,10,10,0; но он не округлился вообще
Помогите, не знаю, что делать. !
Хотелось бы получить такое поле только с округлениями

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqwCv.jpg)

Comment: Вы могли бы добавить к вопросу изображение того, что хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: Обновил, посмотрите

Comment: Вроде этом можно сделать через CSS задав `-fx-broder-radius` и `-fx-background-radius`. Увы это не точная инфа, давно не возился с JavaFX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант на CSS, исходя из размера png-иконок 16х16 ([image: login.png], [image: lock.png]):

// `textfield.css:`

```
.leftpill {
    icon-bg-color: rgb(209,211,214);
    border-color: derive(icon-bg-color, -30%);
    -fx-background-color:    icon-bg-color, border-color, icon-bg-color, border-color, -fx-base;
    -fx-background-insets:   5 1 5 5,       0,            1,             1 1 1 26,     1 1 1 27;
    -fx-background-radius:   0,             3 0 0 3,      3 0 0 3,       0,            0;
    -fx-border-image-slice:  0 0 0 16;
    -fx-border-image-width:  0 0 0 16;
    -fx-border-image-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-border-image-insets: 5 1 5 5;
    -fx-padding: 2 2 2 10;
}

.text-field.leftpill  {
    -fx-border-image-source: url("login.png");
}

.password-field.leftpill {
    -fx-border-image-source: url("lock.png");
}
```

// `textfield.fxml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" stylesheets="@textfield.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.92" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <VBox spacing="12">
        <TextField promptText="Логин" styleClass="leftpill" />
        <PasswordField promptText="Пароль" styleClass="leftpill" />
      <padding>
         <Insets bottom="15.0" left="15.0" right="15.0" top="15.0" />
      </padding>
    </VBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылочка с объяснениями: [9-patch scaling in JavaFX](http://www.software-architect.net/blog/article/date/2015/11/14/9-patch-scaling-in-javafx.html)

Answer (score 0):

Другой вариант — компонент оформления вынесен в отдельный класс `TextFieldDecorator`. Плюс иконки FontAwesome с использованием ControlsFX:

// sample.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import sample.TextFieldDecorator?>

<VBox prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      spacing="12.0">

    <TextFieldDecorator icon="USER">
        <TextField promptText="Логин"/>
    </TextFieldDecorator>

    <TextFieldDecorator icon="LOCK">
        <PasswordField promptText="Пароль"/>
    </TextFieldDecorator>

    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="12.0" left="12.0" right="12.0" top="12.0"/>
    </padding>

</VBox>
```

Результат:

[image: Результат]

Вспомогательный компонент:

// TextFieldDecorator.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.DefaultProperty;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import org.controlsfx.glyphfont.FontAwesome;
import org.controlsfx.glyphfont.Glyph;

import java.io.IOException;

@DefaultProperty("decorated")
public class TextFieldDecorator extends HBox {
    @FXML
    private HBox innerHBox;

    @FXML
    private Glyph glyph;

    public ObservableList<Node> getDecorated() {
        return innerHBox.getChildren();
    }

    public void setIcon(FontAwesome.Glyph iconValue){
        glyph.setIcon(iconValue);
    }

    public FontAwesome.Glyph getIcon(){
        Object icon = glyph.getIcon();
        if(FontAwesome.Glyph.class.isAssignableFrom(icon.getClass()))
        {
            return (FontAwesome.Glyph)icon;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("glyph icon isn't of type FontAwesome.Glyph");
    }

    public TextFieldDecorator() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
                getClass().getResource("TextFieldDecorator.fxml"));

        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

// TextFieldDecorator.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import org.controlsfx.glyphfont.*?>

<fx:root stylesheets="@TextFieldDecorator.css"
         type="javafx.scene.layout.HBox"
         xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
         xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172">
    <children>
        <HBox fx:id="innerHBox" styleClass="text-field-decorator">
            <Glyph fx:id="glyph" fontFamily="FontAwesome" styleClass="glyph">
                <icon>
                    <FontAwesome.Glyph fx:constant="COFFEE" />
                </icon>
            </Glyph>
        </HBox>
    </children>
</fx:root>
```

// TextFieldDecorator.css:

```
.text-field-decorator {
    icon-bg-color: rgb(209,211,214);
    icon-color: derive(icon-bg-color, -50%);
    border-color: derive(icon-bg-color, -30%);
    focused-border-color: derive(border-color, -30%);

    -fx-background-color:    border-color;
    -fx-background-insets:   0;
    -fx-background-radius:   3 0 0 3;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-padding: 1;
    -fx-spacing: 1;
}

.text-field-decorator > .glyph {
    -fx-background-color:    icon-bg-color;
    -fx-background-radius:   2 0 0 2;
    -fx-text-fill: icon-color;
    -fx-max-height: infinity;
    -fx-max-width: infinity;
    -fx-padding: 0 6 0 6;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-min-width: 1.6em;
}

.text-field-decorator > .text-field {
    -fx-background-radius:   0;
    -fx-background-insets:   0;
}

.text-field-decorator > .text-field:focused {
    -fx-border-color: focused-border-color;
    -fx-border-insets: -1;
}
```